# Checar existência de arquivo em Python com função

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções, arquivo

Procurei todos os repositórios correspondentes à minha dúvida aqui, porém todos são bem diretos quando a parte de criação e leitura de arquivos em Python, mas não vi nada relacionado utilizando função.

**Função para criar arquivo e checar se arquivo existe**

```
def cria_arq(nome_arquivo):
# para criar arquivo usando path lib
if not os.path.exists('nome_arquivo'):
    Path(f'{nome_arquivo}.txt').touch()
else:
    print('Já existe um arquivo com este nome!!')
```

**Menu para captar nome do arquivo**

```
def menu_arquivos():
# clear()
title('Navegando pelo Menu ARQUIVOS')
print('Escolha sua opção: ')
op = int(input('''
    [1] - Criar arquivos
    [2] - Ler arquivos
    [3] - Editar arquivos
    [4] - Apagar arquivos
    [0] - Retornar/Sair

    Opção: '''))

if op == 0:
    menu()
elif op == 1:
    # cria_arq(str(input('Nome do arquivo: ')))
    j = 'S'
    while j == 'S':
        cria_arq(str(input('Nome do arquivo: ')))
        j = str(input('Deseja criar um novo arquivo? [S/N]')).upper()
    menu_arquivos()
```

Com base nos códigos acima mostrados eu queria que ao pegar a entrada do usuário o nome do arquivo que ele quer criar, e caso o nome que ele desse de entrada fosse igual a um já existente, a função retornasse que o arquivo já existe e volte para o loop no **menu** para saber se o usuário quer criar um novo arquivo ou não.

Já tentei mudar a linha da função **cria_arq** para essas 3 formas, porém sem sucesso:

```
if not os.path.exists(f'{nome_arquivo}'):
if not os.path.exists('nome_arquivo'):
if not os.path.exists(nome_arquivo):
```

Sou iniciante na linguagem e estou criando uma espécie de Explorer (somente com tratamento de arquivos de texto). O código ainda está em desenvolvimento, aos poucos vou aprimorando conforme vou aprendendo coisas diferentes.

Desde já, agradeço a ajuda de todos!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, tudo bem?

Então o problema está na sua função `cria_arq`, você tem como argumento `nome_arquivo` no entanto você está checando no `if` a string nome_arquivo e não a própria variável.

Veja que você tem que passar o nome do arquivo completo com a sua extensão, caso contrario vai retornar falso.

Por exemplo, suponha que eu tenha um arquivo com nome *file.txt*.

```
os.path.exist('file') # Retorna Falso
os.path.exist('file.txt') # Retorna True
```

Sua função deveria ficar assim (apenas sugestão)

```
def cria_arq(nome_arquivo):
    if not os.path.exists(nome_arquivo):
        Path(nome_arquivo).touch()
    else:
        print('Já existe um arquivo com este nome!!')
```

Caso queria escrever apenas o nome do arquivo e a extensão por separado. Neste caso se a pessoa não digita a extensão, por default o arquivo se ele não existir terá a extensão txt.

```
def cria_arq(nome_arquivo, extensao='txt'):
    file = '.'.join([nome_arquivo, extensao])
    if not os.path.exists(file):
        Path(file).touch()
    else:
        print('Já existe um arquivo com este nome!!')
```

Exemplo:

```
cria_arq('arquivo') # cria a função 'arquivo.txt'
cria_arq('arquivo', 'csv') # cria a função 'arquivo.csv'
```

Comment: Octávio, Obrigado pela ajuda!! Compreendi o que você explicou, porém ainda continuo preso na questão de ter que digitar o '.txt' junto com o nome para criar o arquivo, pois se na hora que chamo a função eu não coloco a extensão, ele cria um arquivo nulo, sendo que preciso dele sendo um .txt. Existe alguma forma de fazer isso? 
Mas sua ajuda foi de grande valia, observando que posso colocar o usuário para informar o formato do arquivo. Obrigado!!!

Comment: Exatamente Adriel, se tu não passa o nome junto com a extensão ele vai criar um arquivo nulo (sem extensão). É possível, sim veja a resposta editada e veja se atende a suas expectativas.

Comment: Atendeu demais, resolveu o problema por completo!! Obrigado de verdade pela ajuda e paciência!! Obrigado